# Bootstrap span2 not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://thegsx.com/bootstrap.htm

For some reason if I do span2 on the fluid-row it causes the div to be 100% wide and breaks the design

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bootstrap-responsive.css file is missing the following block, for some reason:

```
  .row-fluid .span2 {
    width: 14.52991452991453%;
    *width: 14.476723040552828%;
  }
```

Add it back and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the row class on the element that has the class span2.